# pythonの継承で使われるsuper(Conv1d, self)が分かりません。

Tags: python, python3, pytorch

pytorchのコードを見ていたところ、

```
class Conv1d(_ConvNd):
    def __init__(
        self,
        in_channels: int,
        out_channels: int,
        kernel_size: _size_1_t,
        stride: _size_1_t = 1,
        padding: _size_1_t = 0,
        dilation: _size_1_t = 1,
        groups: int = 1,
        bias: bool = True,
        padding_mode: str = 'zeros'  # TODO: refine this type
    ):
        # we create new variables below to make mypy happy since kernel_size has
        # type Union[int, Tuple[int]] and kernel_size_ has type Tuple[int]
        kernel_size_ = _single(kernel_size)
        stride_ = _single(stride)
        padding_ = _single(padding)
        dilation_ = _single(dilation)
        super(Conv1d, self).__init__(
            in_channels, out_channels, kernel_size_, stride_, padding_, dilation_,
            False, _single(0), groups, bias, padding_mode)
```

と、記載があり、

```
        super(Conv1d, self).__init__(
            in_channels, out_channels, kernel_size_, stride_, padding_, dilation_,
            False, _single(0), groups, bias, padding_mode)
```

のsuperが何をしているのかがいまいち理解できません。
自分自身を継承？このコードの意味を教えてください。

Comment: 重複候補: https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/39769/19110